# Building automatic feature and site eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-rcp, tycho

I have a set of plugins in eclipse with a product. My goal is to automate the deliveries: passing automatically test, creating automatically features and update sites... I have found this tutorial http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html#exercisetycho_configuration_parent to automatically build a feature, update site and product with maven tycho ans it's great, but I still have to manually choose the plugins to be exported in the feature or create the category.xml. Is there a way not to do these steps manually?

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: I think you can automate this by writing separate scripts, which could be integrated into your build platform. We have different scripts - bash and ANT for new git projects and old svn projects, to collect changes, automatically increment versions of product, features, plugins to release, depending in which plugins there were changes during development phase, update related Jira tasks and so on.